# Ajax Get not working?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

```
function submitForm()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET', 
        url: 'iccrefresh.php', 
        data: $('this').serialize(),
        dataType:'script',
        error: function()
                { $( "#dialog_error" ).dialog( "open" ); },
        success: function()
                { $( "#dialog_success" ).dialog( "open" ); }
            });
    return false;
}
```

In Php

```
echo "<form name='refresh' onsubmit='return submitForm();'>";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='team1' value=$teamx />";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='team2' value=$teamy />";
echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' align='middle' value='Refresh Match Score'/>";
echo "</form>";
```

Is there any reason why I am not able to send team 1 and team 2 across? I am getting a success message, but iccrefresh is unable to access team 1 and team 2 values?

Comment: Does it fall into to error or success?

Comment: 'dateType' should be 'dataType' ...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there doesn't exists a tag with the name `this`. You have to write `$(this)` instead of `$('this')`...

But this is also wrong here, you have to pass the `this` (the element) into the function and then use it as "*selector*":

```
function submitForm(form)
{
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET', 
        url: 'iccrefresh.php', 
        data: $(form).serialize(),
        dataType:'script',
        error: function()
                { $( "#dialog_error" ).dialog( "open" ); },
        success: function()
                { $( "#dialog_success" ).dialog( "open" ); }
            });
    return false;
}
```

And in PHP:

```
echo "<form name='refresh' onsubmit='return submitForm(this);'>";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='team1' value='$teamx' />";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='team2' value='$teamy' />";
echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' align='middle' value='Refresh Match Score'/>";
echo "</form>";
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not enclose this in quotes, `$('this')` will find the tag name `this` and will not refer to current `form` object.

*Change*

```
data: $('this').serialize(),
```

*To*

```
data: $(this).serialize(),
```

Also you are using javascript to bind event, so you need to pass the source explicitly.

*Html*

```
echo "<form name='refresh' onsubmit='return submitForm();'>";
```

*Javascript*

```
function submitForm(formobj)
{
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET', 
        url: 'iccrefresh.php', 
        data: $(formobj).serialize(),
        dateType:'script',
        error: function()
                { $( "#dialog_error" ).dialog( "open" ); },
        success: function()
                { $( "#dialog_success" ).dialog( "open" ); }
            });
    return false;
}
```

Comment: which is this? explain it to JS... (you're not in a class/closure context)

Comment: This in a string like that suggests he may have a <this /> tag though; but I do agree it is a bit iffy

Answer (score 0):

Remove datatype 'script'. You are getting back html from the request, so jquery should parse it for you

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
echo "<form name='refresh' onsubmit='return submitForm();'>";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='team1' value='".$teamx."' />";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='team2' value='".$teamy."' />";
echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' align='middle' value='Refresh Match Score'/>";
echo "</form>";
```

Comment: The php appears to be fine, you can use variable from within stings like he has